# Twitter API implementing "trending"

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API to list trending topics. After calling my function and assigning to "X" (then printing "X") I am returned (parsed in JSON) something that looks like this:

```
puts X

{"trends"=>[{"name"=>"blah blah", "query" =>"blah blah" and a bunch more info...
            {"name"=>"blah2 blah2", "query"=>"blah blah" and a bunch more...
            {"name"=>"blah3 blah3", and so on and so forth.}]}
```

I can get closer to my desired output by calling

```
X.each do |T|
  puts T["trends"]
end
```

I can get it to print each line like so:

```
{"name"=>"blah blah", "query" =>"blah blah" and a bunch more information
{"name"=>"blah2 blah2", "query"=>"blah blah" and a bunch more...
{"name"=>"blah3 blah3", and so on and so forth.}
```

How would I go about getting my code to just print the name of the trending topic? I was thinking it would be something along the lines of

```
X.each do |T|
  puts T["trends"]["name"]
end
```

but that isn't working. How would I get it to just display

```
blah  blah
blah2 blah2
blah3 blah3
```

As per diego
When I call the following I get a no conversion from String to Integer error.

```
X["trends"].each do |T|
    puts T["name"]
end
```

And when I call X.inspect I just get what I put at the top of the question, with a set of [] added around trends.

```
[{"trends"=>[{"name"=>"blah blah", "query" =>"blah blah" and a bunch more info...
            {"name"=>"blah2 blah2", "query"=>"blah blah" and a bunch more...
            {"name"=>"blah3 blah3", and so on and so forth.}]}]
```

I figured it out.

```
X.each do |trend|
    trend["trends"].each do |topic|
        puts topic["name"]
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post what you get when you inspect the T variable inside that block? try `puts T.inspect`

Comment: Hmm... it actually seems I am getting the same output as if I printed X. Calling inspect on X seems to add a [] bracket around everything, but simply printing X gives the same result as calling T.inspect

Comment: I figured it out and added the answer to my question. Thanks for the help diego. I tried to upvote you but it says my reputation is too low. I marked you as the right answer though because it did lead me to figuring it out.

Comment: There, I gave you a few upvotes. Happy stackoverflowing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over `'trends'`:

```
response = {"trends"=>[{"name"=>"blah blah", "query" =>"blah blah" and a bunch more information
            {"name"=>"blah2 blah2", "query"=>"blah blah" and a bunch more...
            {"name"=>"blah3 blah3", and so on and so forth.}]}

response['trends'].each do |trend|
  trend['name'] # do what you want with this
end
```

Or to get an array of all the names:

```
response['trends'].map { |t| t['name'] }
# => ["blah blah", "blah2 blah2", "blah3 blah3"]
```

Comment: When I try X["trends"].each do |T|
               T["name"]
           end
I get '[]': no iplicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: Seems like the data you're working with doesn't match up to what you posted in your question. Whatever variable you have that contains the 'trends' key (`response` in my answer) call inspect on it and post it to your question

Comment: OK. I was trying to add it in the comment but the code isn't appearing right. I'll add it to my question.